# Android SDK Download Interrupted

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools, macos-sierra

I'm on:

```
Mac OS Sierra
Android Studio 2.2
```

Trying to install

```
Google APIs Intel x86 Atom-64 System Image, Android API 24, revision 7
```

I'm always getting:

```
Download interrupted: Operation timed out
```

I'm using the standalone Android SDK Manager, but I receive the same result using the one bundled inside Android Studio. How can I solve that? I need the image to use the emulator. The manager is connecting via HTTPS and the download starts correctly, after some minutes I get the error. I suspect some problem with Sierra and permissions. Anyone has the same issue?

Comment: You could download these installers from something like this: http://www.april1985.com/android-sdk-offline/ via browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try bypassing the proxy if you are in any, in case you are in company network, choose for the internet or guest version of your wifi and disable proxy.

Comment: I'm not behind a proxy and my network is not changed. With the same configuration I was able to download on mac os x and studio 2.1.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this restarting the download 4 times. Each time the download was resumed from incremental percentage (let's say 24%, 60%, 74%) and in the last temptative the install process was ok. Anyway that's not a real solution. P.S. I've a large bandwidth with low ping.

Comment: That is the ideal solution actually.. Its also in the recommended guide in some application which has large file size.